# How to restore installed packages from backup

Tags: package-management, backup

I keep `/home`, `/etc`, and `/usr/local` backed up.  My hard drive crashed and I reinstalled Ubuntu and copied over my backed-up directories.  (Yay for backups!)

I assumed that something in `/etc` would tell the package manager what I want to have installed.  Apparently it doesn't work that way.  I would like to re-install all the packages that I had previously installed.  Is there something in my backed-up files that would tell me what I had installed?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The list of packages that you had installed was kept in `/var/lib/dpkg/status`, with daily backups of the dpkg database to `/var/backups`. These directories unfortunately aren't in the list of directories that you backed up.

Comment: And if I DO have /var/lib/dpkg/status , and restore it - will it restore all the packages that I had?

Comment: Please answer this.

Comment: in this answer is explained how to restore packages from `/var/lib/pdkg/status` http://unix.stackexchange.com/a/161940/8115